# エディットモード中の見えていない部分の辺や頂点を非表示にしたい

Tags: blender

Blender2.79を使用しています。
エディットモード中にカメラからは見えていない部分の頂点や辺も全て表示されてしまい、編集しづらくて困っています。

オブジェクトモードとエディットモードの比較画像です。
カメラからは見えないはずの辺が表示されているのがわかるかと思います。ググったりメッシュのプロパティや設定を色々いじったのですが解決出来ませんでした。

- オブジェクトモードでの表示

  [image: オブジェクトモード]
- エディットモードでの表示

  [image: エディットモード]

このくらいのポリゴン数なら問題ないですが、人の顔とかだと後ろの髪の毛の頂点や辺が見えてしまいどれがどれやら意味不明な事になります。

- とあるモデルの顔を近くで写したもの

  [image: 顔近影]

初歩的な質問になりますが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

深度バッファのクリップをオンにすれば非表示になると思います。 [image]

参考: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:JA/2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes